# How to find href by title using select()?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to find `href` for page which have `title` that I given. For example I have `title` **Italy**,
and on wikipedia I want to get `href` for page,which have this `title`. This is my code:

```
                if status_code_finish == 200:
                    list_of_titles_finish = [title.get('title') for title in
                                             soup_finish.find(f'title*="{finish}"]')]
```

arg **finish** is **Italy**

How can I do like:

```
title.get('title') for title in soup.finish.find(f'title= {finish}')
```

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily - For example it should clarify role of `title` (attribute/tag). Also take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to select your elements more specific and in a single statement, without concatenating several `find()` or `find_all()` - Simply use the [`attribute selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and `*` for contains:

```
pattern = 'Italy'    
[a.get('title') for a in soup.select(f'a[title*="{pattern}"]')]
```

or with a `list` of pattern:

```
pattern = ['Italy','Finland']
set(a.get('title') for p in pattern for a in soup.select(f'a[title*="{p}"]'))
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<a href="/wiki/Italy" title="Italy">Italy</a>
<a href="/wiki/Italy" title="Italy Finland">Italy Finland</a>
<a href="/wiki/Finland" title="Finland">Finland</a>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

pattern = 'Italy'    
[a.get('title') for a in soup.select(f'a[title*="{pattern}"]')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `soup.find_all()` with the constraint of `title=finish` to make a `list` of finish title. After that, you could just iterate through it.